# text of an UILabel is blurred when the position is not a whole value?

Tags: ios, uilabel, frame

I am developing an application in iOS 6 , It is something like form filling application.
I use XML for drawing the UI elements, my problem is that whenever the x,y positions of
UILable is in integer like x="43" y="165" the texts are fine but when I get position as float value like  x="43.5" y="165.2" the text is looking blurred or look like bold applied like in the below images

x="43" y="165"

[image: Correct Image]

x="43.5" y="165.2"

[image: Blurred Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal. Because your text is rendered in some sub-pixel area. That means you cannot make a pixel on the device display both your text and the background. But this should be fine if you use .5 position value in Retina Display. Because 1 point on Retina Display is 2 pixel.

Answer (score 2):

since you can't render halve a pixel, text placed on halve pixels will get blurred as the rendering system will try and render the halve pixel.

What you can do in `round` the coordinates to make sure that there not halve pixels.